# d3 real time chart legend design

Tags: d3.js

This is the final updated code. In a update function that takes a dataset object this code will render a real time legend. Other chart elements can be initialized when the script is loaded and the enter, update and exit selections for those belong in the update function as well. Maybe it is useful.  Was for me. I think I can add this to any chart.  [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/aq5uqnk2/)

```
 var legendG = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data(donut(dataset), function (d) {
                  return d.data.label;
              })

    var legendEnter = legendG.enter();


    legendEnter = legendEnter.append("g")
               .attr("class", "legend");

    //Now merge Enter and Update and adjust the location
    legendEnter.merge(legendG)
            .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + (width 
    - 350) + "," + (i * 15 + 20) + ")"; })
            .attr("class", "legend");

    legendG.exit().remove();

    // Apend only to the enter selection
    legendEnter.append("text")
         .text(function (d) {
             return d.data.label;

         })
         .style("font-size", 12)
         .attr("y", 10)
         .attr("x", 11);


    //Now merge Enter and Update the legend color
    legendEnter.merge(legendG)
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {

            console.log('index: ' + i + ' ' + d.data.label)
            var c = color(i);
            return c;
        });
```

Comment: The index is only used for color. Is the issue that you are not getting the same color for the values when the data changes?

Comment: No, its that the initial load with all the data works fine. the index * 15 + 20 places the legend items; (index 0 through 5 for example) then new data gets added, the new enter() also uses indexes starting at zero.   since it is used to place the items they overlay the previous items still in the data set. The code works, (update  enter exit ) only item placement is off. Notice the transform.  The exit works, MY design is flawed :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the `transform` attribute of the `update` and `enter` selection together after merging the selection:

```
 var legendG = svg.selectAll(".legend")
           .data(donut(dataset), function (d) {
               return d.data.label;
           })

      var  legendEnter= legendG.enter().append("g")
                 .attr("class", "legend");  


      //Now merge Enter and Updatge and adjust the location
      legendEnter.merge(legendG)
           .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + (width - 500) + "," + (i * 15 + 20) + ")"; })
           .attr("class", "legend");    


      legendG.exit().remove();

      // Apend only to the enter selection
      legendEnter.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
              return color(i);
          });
    ...
```

Updated fiddle from previous post:[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7fc4es0/2/)

Comment: I think I get it! LegendEnter and legendG are 'merged' then the i will be unique and the legend item will not overlap.. is that right? Wow

Comment: Yes. That is why I like d3, it is powerful and simple.